# React state is undefined after using .fetch from local json with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I used useEffect to fetch data from a json stored locally, and to set initial state of component. Currently, `console.log(header)` does properly log the object. However, when I uncomment the `{/* {header.name} */}` part, the console.log shows that the header is the default value `[]`. Why is this happening?

```
function App() {

  const [allData, setAllData] = useState();
  const [header, setHeader] =  useState([]);
  const [sections, setSections] = useState([]);

  const getData=()=>{
    fetch('data.json',{
         headers : { 
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Accept': 'application/json'
          }
        }
       )
        .then(function(response){
           console.log(response)
           return response.json();
         })
          .then(function(myJson) {

             console.log(myJson);
             setHeader(myJson[0].header)
             setSections(myJson[0].sections)
           });
     }

  useEffect(()=>{
    getData()
  },[])
    
  console.log(sections)
  console.log(header)

    
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      Hello world
      {/* {header.name} */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You sure it is `undefined` instead of `[]` (i.e. the default value)? `setState` is async, so it may not be set when you output it to the console.  If you really want to reliably output it, wrap it in `useEffect`. `useEffect(() => console.log(header), [header])`

Comment: Is myJson[0].header an array ?

Comment: @MatthewKwong Apologies, you are right, it is the default value `[]`. 

@MohitKushwaha `myJson` is an array, `myJson[0]` is a json

Comment: Sorry, but I was trying to know that header property of myjson[0] is an array or not

Answer (score 0):

UseEffect acts asynchronously, meaning the first time the component renders you won't have fetched those data just yet (to see that, have a different useEffect with no dependency array and console log the header value in there).

To sort this, add the optional chaining operator, `{header?.name}` so that it will display only once those data are fetched.

Bit on a side, since the header is an object I'd suggest you have your initial value set to `null` rather than an empty array